# What's the use of an empty mbox{}

Tags: memoir

Consider the following declaration from the `memoir` manual:

```
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]%
  {\parbox[t][0pt]{6em}{\itshape\raggedleft\mbox{} #1}}
```

What is the use of the empty mbox in this command?

Comment: For those who don't immediately recall the definition of `\mbox`: it's `\long\def\mbox#1{\leavevmode\hbox{#1}}` (from line 4573 of `latex.ltx`, i.e., the LaTeX kernel).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably `\mbox` is used to get out of the vertical mode because of the `\parbox` to switch to paragraph mode. For example, `#1` may start with a `\color` command. In vertical mode, the color whatsit is set at the top of the vertical list, then the title text starts a new paragraph, which is placed below the color whatsit.
The reference point of the top aligned `\paragraph` is then the color whatsit. This reference point is then aligned with the current base line. As result the head title moves *below* the current base line.

The `\leavevmode` of `\mbox` avoids this situation by leaving the vertical mode and entering horizontal mode by starting the new paragraph. Then the color whatsit is just put on the current base line along with the following title text.

I do not think, that the empty `\hbox{}` part of `\mbox{}` serves a purpose here, `\mbox{}` is just a little shorter to type than `\leavevmode` or `\noindent`. However the definition contains a bug caused by the following space. The space after `\mbox{}` is *not* ignored because of the horizontal mode. That means the text for the first line does not have the full `6em`, its line width is reduced by the width of that space.

A fixed definition would be:

```
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{6em}{%
    \itshape
    \raggedleft
    \leavevmode % or \mbox{}% without following space
    #1%
  }%
}
```

Comment: Fixed in the memoir development version

Answer (score 7):

Compare the difference.  The `\mbox` will get you out of vertical mode.  Here, `\marginbox` is as you defined it; `\xmarginbox` eliminates the `\mbox{}` in the definition.

Macros like `\vspace`, `\llap`, and `\rlap` behave differently in vertical vs. horizontal mode.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\marginbox}[1]%
  {\parbox[t][0pt]{6em}{\itshape\raggedleft\mbox{} #1}}
\newcommand{\xmarginbox}[1]%
  {\parbox[t][0pt]{6em}{\itshape\raggedleft #1}}
\begin{document}
x\marginbox{\vspace{\baselineskip}y}\par
x\xmarginbox{\vspace{\baselineskip}y}\par
\vspace{3em}
x\marginbox{\llap{xyz}}\par
x\xmarginbox{\llap{xyz}}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]